# Compatibility of free/malloc between compilers

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

Suppose I have a library compiled with compiler A.  It allocates memory using `malloc()` and leaves it to me to `free()` it.  It provides no special free function.

Can I compile my program (that uses this library) with compiler B?  Or do I have to worry that one compiler's (standard library's) `malloc` is incompatible with the other's `free`?

In addition to the general question I would also like to know the answer specifically for these compilers: system clang on OS X with MacPorts' gcc 4.9 or 5.

Comment: Generally speaking a library compiled with compiler A is *not* compatible with compiler B. Even if compilation succeeds there is no guarantee that the generated program will work properly. That being said, clang does aim to be compatible with gcc, so it *might* work, however that behaviour is completely compiler dependant and would have to be tested specifically in your case.

Comment: @UnholySheep Your comment is incorrect for almost anything but Windows. There is something called an ABI to ensure this compatibility. This is a bit more fuzzy on Windows where different compiler vendors have/had different calling conventions, but on UNIX-like operating systems there has always been a single ABI for each operating system so libraries produced by one compiler can interoperate with libraries compiled by another one. Of course, you can purposefully break this if you try really hard but it works in all but such cases.

Comment: Clang and GCC play just fine together on MacOSX. In both cases, `malloc` and `free` are provided by libc.dylib - which ships with the operating system rather than the compiler.  If compiling C++, you can even mix and match clang's libc++ and GNU libstdc++ together in the same executable. 

Also be aware, that if you've installed the Xcode command-line tools option, invoking `gcc` from the command line will actually give you `clang`, and the vast majority of the time, this is not an issue.

Comment: It should at least be said this is a bad library design, simply for the reason you are asking.  Because of that, answers to your questions for the 2nd paragraph are I think _if_ you can compile your program with compiler B, then _yes_, you should worry about incompatibilities of the library which was compiled in compiler A.  (regarding @FUZxxi's comment, this comment is from someone who spends majority of time on Windows)

Comment: @marko  -  _[for] the vast majority of the time, this is not an issue_.  This would not give me comfort.  It is X that would worry me, where `X == (all time) - (vast majority of time)`

Comment: @FUZxxl Windows does *not* guarantee malloc/free compatibility that OP mentions. Any compiler/library is free to implement their own allocator. You are supposed to use Windows API allocators if you want that compatibility (e.g. GlobalAlloc, LocalAlloc)

Comment: @M.M Which is why I said that your comment is incorrect for anything but Windows.

Comment: @FUZxxl sorry,  I read your comment inverted somehow :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shouldn't be a problem. The operating system's ABI specifies how programs call library functions, and all programs and libraries are supposed to conform to this. This allows you to link programs created with different compilers together.

Your question indicates a confusion between compilers and libraries. Compiling a library with compiler A doesn't mean it uses Library A's `malloc` function. Libraries are specified during the link step, not when compiling the library. When you create the executable program, you link the main program with the library you compiled and the C runtime library. `malloc` and `free` are provided in the C runtime library, and there will just be one of them in the resulting executable.

Comment: I don't know what the ABI specification touches on. Can I assume then that everything that's in the C standard library (including `free` and `malloc`) will be interoperable? I was worried because many libraries provide their own free functions for these purpose (but some don't).

Comment: Can we really assume that two implementations of `malloc` are compatible? I would think not. My understanding of the question is that it is not asking about the ABI or API but the internal implementation. For example, `malloc` from libarary A might be implemented with fixed blocks whilst `malloc` for library B might have variable sized blocks (simple example). So you can't call `malloc` from one library and `free` from the other.

Comment: When you link with a library, you get all its functions. So if you're using library A's `malloc`, you're also using its `free`, and they will work together.

Comment: But that's not what the OP is asking. For whatever reason OP is specifically asking about `malloc` from one library and `free` from another.

Comment: @AlanAu Then he's asking about something that doesn't actually happen. You can't pick and choose functions from different libraries, AFAIK.

Comment: Agreed. So the answer to OP's question is actually "No, they can't be assumed to be compatible". With a follow up question of - why are you doing his and do you really need to?

Comment: The problem is that he's confusing compilers with libraries. He says "library compiled with compiler A". Just because it's compiled with compiler A doesn't mean it uses library A's `malloc` function.

Comment: Yep, that's another thing to point out - `malloc/free` is not tied to the compiler.

Comment: @Szabolcs I've added more details to the answer, explaining the separation between compiler and libraries.

Comment: @Barmer -  regarding _malloc and free are provided in the C runtime library_...  OP specifically set the conditions that the version of `free()` used in compiled program  B is _not included_ in the library provided by compiler A in which `[m][c]alloc()` are provided.  However unlikely, that is the question that was asked and should be answered.

Comment: His question is based on a misconception of how compiling and linking work. I can't answer nonsense on its own terms, the best I can do is explain how things really work.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, this is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

`free` and `malloc` are not always compatible between compilers.  Specifically, [they are not compatible between MSVC and MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Interoperability_of_Libraries_Created_by_Different_Compiler_Brands).

I encountered the following situation:

I was using a C library that has a function that returns an array.  The array must be `free`d by the user when no longer needed.  I was using a precompiled DLL of this library using MSVC.  However, the DLL was compiled with MinGW.  Using MSVC's `free` on memory that was allocated with MinGW's `malloc` causes a crash.  But ensuring that `free`/`malloc` are always used in compatible pairs avoided the trouble, even if my program used a different C compiler than the DLL.